# wso2 NullPointer when deploying carbon application BankingSample_1.0.0.car

Tags: deployment, wso2

Following this closely every step :

https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS370/Retail+Banking+Sample

activemq server 5.10.0 is up and running. when attempting the step of starting(deploying) the BankingSample on the AS server I get the following error

```
[2014-07-28 15:01:01,450]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent} -  Mgt Console URL  : https://192.168.0.68:9443/carbon/
[2014-07-28 15:01:06,220]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at     [2014-07-28 15:01:06,216+0200]
[2014-07-28 15:03:05,111]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at     [2014-07-28 15:03:05,111+0200]
[2014-07-28 15:03:14,887]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager} -  Deploying Carbon Application : BankingSample_1.0.0.car...
[2014-07-28 15:03:14,998] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.CappAxis2Deployer} -  Error while deploying carbon application E:\wso\wso2as-5.2.1\repository\deployment\server\carbonapps\BankingSample_1.0.0.car
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.AppDeployerUtils.areAllFeaturesInstalled(AppDeployerUtils.java:559)
at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.AppDeployerUtils.buildAcceptanceList(AppDeployerUtils.java:583)
at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.handler.DefaultAppDeployer.isAccepted(DefaultAppDeployer.java:214)
at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.handler.DefaultAppDeployer.deployRecursively(DefaultAppDeployer.java:154)
at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.handler.DefaultAppDeployer.deployArtifacts(DefaultAppDeployer.java:71)
at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager.deployCarbonApp(ApplicationManager.java:251)
at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.CappAxis2Deployer.deploy(CappAxis2Deployer.java:71)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:371)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:59)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:67)
at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.runAxisDeployment(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:79)
at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:124)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:181)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:205)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Any one experience this problem ? Any ideas on how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, used extractnow to extract archive which recursively extracted other archives.

Comment: I also get the same issue when following this sample. How did you solve it?